# generating bi-gram from a sentence in the list

Tags: python, list, n-gram

i have a list which contains sentences split up from a test paragraph. I'm trying to generate bi-grams from this list of sentences. but i'm getting :

```
<itertools.izip object at 0x029E5080>
```

My code:

.....

```
    print (words3) 
    print (words4)
```

Comment: Please indent your code correctly before posting it here, in python indentation is important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not an error message, that's the result of

```
 print (words3)
```

because `words3` is an object of type `itertools.izip`. You might want to

```
print(list(words3))
```

or

```
for w in words3:
    print 3
```

instead.

Answer (score 2):

`<itertools.izip object at 0x029E5080>` is not an error, it is the iterator object, if you want to print your bigrams, try this :

```
print([word for word in words3])     # or replace the list comprehension by list(words3) as pointed out by @larsmans
print([word for word in words4])
```

instead of your

```
print(words3) 
print(words4)
```

Answer (score 1):

To print elements of an iterator convert it to a list first. That is, `print list(words3)` rather than `print words3`